# How to deal with situation where LSTM fails to learn (constantly makes the same incorrect prediction)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, keras

I am trying to use LSTM neural networks in order to make a song composer. Basically this is based of a text generator (tries to predict the next character after looking at a sequence of characters) but instead of characters, it tried to predict notes.

Structure of the midi file that serves as the input (Y-axis is the pitch or note value while X-axis is time):
[image]

And this is the predicted note values:
[image]
[image]

I set an epoch of 50, but it seems that the LSTM's loss rate does not decrease, most of the time its loss rate does not improve.

[image]

I suspect this is because there is an overwhelming number of a particular note (in this case, note value 65) which makes the LSTM lazy during training phase and predict 65 each and every time.

I feel like this is a common problem among LSTMs and time-series based learning algorithms. How would I solve a problem like this? If what I mentioned is not the problem, then what is the problem and how do I solve that?

Comment: What is the final activation in the LSTM? And what is the full architecture of your net?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recurrent neural network and use a RProp minus trainer without weight backtracking (aka RProp-, cf. [Igel&Huesken, Neurocomputing 50, 2003]) and without ponderation, ie. all training samples have the same weight.

Comment: The LSTM network *is* a type of RNN.

Answer (score 0):

We need more details besides what you've provided here.

1. What does your data look like?

   - Are you sure you don't have a bug in your data?
2. What does your LSTM architecture look like?

   - Are you sure you're outputting the softmax for your output layer?
3. What are your hyperparameters?

   - Did you set the learning rate too high? If everything else is correct, it's probably this.

Also, are the notes you have for your prediction mapped to Keras as categories/indices? Need to make sure it's not treating them as real-valued numbers.